# imagecopyresized color jpeg doesn't work

Tags: php, image-uploading, php-gd

Hey guys i have a problem with merging two pictures...
I am trying to merge an png file (called badge) with an useruploaded picture. 
Everything works fine when the user upload a png oder gif file, but if he uploads a jpeg image the output image looks really weird. It seems it is an color problem.

[image: This is an successfully badged image]

[image: And this happen with an jpeg image]

Here my code:

```
//Calculate position for badge (right bottom corner)
    $badgeRightPosition = $imageWidth - $badgeWidth; 
    $badgeLeftPosition = $imageHeight - $badgeHeight; 

    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));
    $badge = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($badge));

    $trueColorImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imageWidth, $imageHeight);
   imagealphablending($trueColorImage, true);
   imagesavealpha($trueColorImage, true);

   imagealphablending($badge, true);
   imagesavealpha($badge, true);

   imagealphablending($image, true);
   imagesavealpha($image, true);

imagecopyresized($trueColorImage, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight);
imagecopyresized($trueColorImage, $badge, $badgeRightPosition, $badgeLeftPosition, 0, 0, $imageWidth, $imageHeight, $badgeWidth, $badgeHeight);
```

Comment: And how are you doing this? Providing some code would help you get an answer.

Comment: i also have to say that if the uploaded picture is bigger than the allowed max. width then the image will be resized. 
And exactly here is the problem… after the resize the image (if it is type of jpg) will be damaged

Comment: Does is help to use imagecopyresampled() instead of imagecopyresized()?

Comment: No, but i used a workaround, instead of trying to solve the problem i convert the incoming picture to a png file using imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($image));` I would try to directly open the file

```
$imgsrc = @ImageCreateFromJPEG($image);
if (!$imgsrc) $imgsrc = @ImageCreateFromPNG($image);
if (!$imgsrc) $imgsrc = @ImageCreateFromGIF($image);
if (!$imgsrc) $imgsrc = @ImageCreateFromWBMP($image);
```

Or check the file type by its ending and then use one of the functions above according to the file ending.